# Firebase rules which allow update some value after send specified data

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to define rules to enable increment some value when new data is added? For example, I have structure like this:

```
"products": {
 {
      "productId" : 1,     
      ...,
      "counter" : 0
 }
```

}

and

```
"opinions" : {
  {
      "productId" : 1,
      ...
  }
}
```

I want to increment counter in first product (productId = 1) each time new opinion was added to this product.

Comment: Firebase has Security rules which are useful for authorizations and validations. What you want to accomplish can be done by using the data modification API only, far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a firebase transaction for this.
See this page https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html where they have a similar example.